# Why aren't AC LED lamps as simple as a huge LED array in series?

Tags: led, ac

I do know that it is a very bad idea, as the saying goes with

> Don't think handling AC is simple. Ever.

Why ***exactly*** wouldn't a simple 100+ LED array direct connected to AC work?

A double rectifier bridge would even ensure a flickerless 60Hz.

[image: AC LED Matrix]

Comment: The issue isn’t AC as such but more due to the short and long term variation of the mains voltage supplied to our houses.

Comment: Your limiting resistor would need to be oversized to account for the variance of the voltage of the LED and produce lots of heat yielding a very inefficient system, this is why usually an active current regulation is used.

Comment: _"... ensure a flickerless 60Hz."_ - 60Hz is not flickerless.

Comment: Please simulate it. What duty cycle do you get (n*Vf over the instantaneous voltage)? What peak to average LED current do you get? How much light output (average LED current) compared to running it with same peak current at DC? How much do you need to oversize your (number of) LEDs to make up for that difference? How much more would that cost you? How much cheaper would a constant current driver be?

Comment: @marcelm A full wave bridge would produce 120 Hz pulses - probably close to being flickerless.

Comment: @PStechPaul _"A full wave bridge would produce 120 Hz pulses"_ - True, but that's not what OP wrote ;) - _"probably close to being flickerless."_ - Meh, I can see that in the corner of my eyes, and it's pretty annoying. Wouldn't qualify as flickerless to me.

Comment: To test the "flickerless" - connect a properly sized diode in series with an incandescent light bulb. Connect them to the mains. Evaluate the result. With LEDs, the flickering is expected to be even more visible.

Comment: @virolino Flickering is particularly visible with things that are moving quickly, too. Try waving your hand back and forth under the light and see if it looks strobe-y or not. My apartment has (unfortunately permanently-installed) lights that flicker at 120 Hz and it's not noticeable normally, but quick movement makes it obvious.

Comment: The 100 or 120 Hz flicker can be dangerous - in a machine shop, a lathe running at certain speeds can appear stationary under this kind of light (in my day, fluorescent tubes were the main culprit; thankfully most LED bulbs run much faster, and/or have overlapping duty cycles).

Comment: @virolino Who said I was trying to invalidate your point? You were talking about testing flicker, I added another way you can test for flicker.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the same reason that you never connect a single LED directly to a voltage source:  LEDs are current controlled devices, not voltage controlled.

You want to send a specific amount of current through an LED rather than giving it a specific voltage.

Your example circuit shows a series resistor for current limiting, so you are aware of the need to control the current.

Given the currents and voltages involved, a series resistor would waste a fair amount of power - it would need to have a fairly high power rating, and it would still run warm (if not hot.)

LED lamps such as you propose are actually made, but they use a series capacitor to limit the current.

Here's the schematic diagram of an LED bulb I disassembled a couple of years ago:

[image]

The resistors are there to discharge the capacitors when the bulb is off.  The current limiting is provided by C1.  It has an impedance of about 3.5 kΩ at 50 Hz, which limits the current to a peak of about 175 mA.

The reason this is a bad idea is that the line voltage is not all that well regulated.  This circuit depends on a fixed line voltage to keep the current below the rated limit for the LEDs.  AC outlets get voltage surges, and the voltage may be somewhat higher than the nominal 120 VAC or 230 VAC at all times.

Those line voltage variations result in things like this:

[image]

That's the bulb that belongs to the schematic.  One of the LEDs has a burned black line across it—too much current or too much voltage killed it.

The dead LED failed open - the bulb no longer lit up.

An LED lamp can be as simple as your proposed circuit, it just doesn't work very well.

Comment: aand if that dead LED become a short instead of open when failing, the others would get more voltage over each of them, probably causing (some of) the rest to fail too.

Comment: Many LED bulbs, even those with a current regulator circuit, drive the LEDs above their recommended maximum current. This provides more light with the same number of LEDs, but lifetime is severely shortened (which may be done on purpose).

Comment: How did you arrive at a current of 175 mA (which would be quite al lot for LEDs)?

Comment: 175mA is the short circuit current through C1.  The circuit board with the LEDs has an aluminum core to act as a heat sink for the LEDs.  Those aren't your typical indicator LEDs rated for 20mA.  They are white LEDs intended for higher current.  How much higher, I don't know.  They aren't marked with any kind of part number.

Comment: That means you assumed a voltage of 605 V. Was that really what you wanted to do?

Comment: @Elec1:  Worst case, peak to peak for 230VAC.  Yes.

Comment: More complex drive circuits are also often used, and every bulb I've dismantled has died through a drive circuit failure, whether simple or complex, rather than through emitter failure

Comment: for more circuits and LED bulb analysis and hacks, BigCliveDotCom on YT is great source of knowledge and entertainment.

Answer (score 5):

> Why exactly wouldn't a simple 100+ LED array direct connected to AC work?

If you replace the resistor with a linear current regulator then you would have a typical American light bulb.  The regulator does exactly the same thing as the resistor (turn voltage into heat) but adds two additional features:

1. Thermal limiting.  UL-certification requires that light bulbs have temperature limiting for safety reasons, so simple resistive/capacitive current limiting elements are (I believe) not allowed.
2. Regulation.  With a resistor or capacitor variation in line voltage changes the bulb brightness.  With a linear regulator, that only happens if the line voltage changes enough to put the regulator into drop out.

> A double rectifier bridge would even ensure a flickerless 60Hz.

A full wave rectifier turns 60 Hz into 120 Hz, which still flickers.  To get rid of flicker you need enough capacitance that the ripple on the rectifier never puts the linear regulator into drop out.  There is a tradeoff here, with more voltage wasted across the linear regulator giving better resistance to flicker (but also a hotter bulb that will burn out sooner).